# setting minimum width of div

Tags: html

I have a page with many different objects of different widths.  I am not setting the width of the div that the objects are within as I want it to be able to expand to include whatever items are within it.  But I do want the div to have a minimum width.  Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is very possible. Just use CSS `min-width`. [The MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/min-width) has details.

Comment: Remember this is not ie6 friendly.

Answer (score 11):

Use CSS:

```
min-width
```

**Definition and Usage**

> *The min-width property sets the minimum width of an element. Note: The
>   min-width property does not include
>   padding, borders, or margins!*

like

```
#example {
  width: 150px;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: I recently read that minwidth takes no effect if you specify absolute values for width. The article said to use percentage for width and absolute for minwidth:  https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/min-width/

Answer (score 1):

Checkout some real documentation regarding this, [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/min-width).

Answer (score 0):

this is achievable via css;

```
element
{
    min-width:100px;
}
```