# Make a tall image responsive with snap scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a high resolution image I want to use for a simple yet responsive "coming soon page." The image is 3 times taller than it is wide **and itself contains** a logo and some centered text strewn across three panes as in [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odkvj.png).

To make this webpage work on both large and small screens it would be great to

1. Auto resize the image height to 3 times the browser height
2. Maintain aspect ratio
3. Set a minimum image pixel width so that "Widest Text Blurb" is never cutoff
4. Allow the image to overflow as necessary to accomplish 1. without creating a horizontal scroll bar
5. It would be awesome to scroll snap between panes.

**Parts Of The Solution**

1. In the beginning I was using `vw` or `vh` on width or height settings but perhaps I should be scaling to something other than the viewport.
2. Aspect ratio is maintained by specifying the width, or the height, but not both,
3. Just use CSS [min-width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042733/setting-minimum-width-of-div)
4. This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865128/how-to-center-an-image-that-is-wider-than-the-browser-window-not-a-background-i) and answered [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/seepW/36/?123456) help but breaks when I try scaling the image.
5. I've experimented with cutting the image into 3 different images and placing them in divs in this [scroll snap demo](http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/Basic-Full-Window-Page-Scoll-Plugin-with-jQuery-PageScroll.html) but the panes end up overlapping. Scrolling wouldn't necessarily have to show an entire pane but should snap to the horizontal center of a pane

**How can I mix the partial solutions above (or others) to make an image scale as described?** I have a ton of failed Fiddles I could share but none of them really give a starting advantage.

**UPDATE**
The text depicted in the imgr link isn't a placeholder for text that will be in divs but is itself in the image. Apologies for any confusion

Comment: Sure... this is probably a terrible way to make a webpage but it'll do in the short term

Comment: 3. and 4. seem like they aren't possible together. You want to limit the horizontal width so the boxes aren't cut off, but you don't want horizontal scrollbars. What would happen when you reach the minimum width?

Comment: Possibly yes and no. Per  4. and its fiddle you can see that changing the width of the screen doesn't cause a scroll bar to appear. However, if the image can resize and has a minimum width, then maybe a scroll bar would appear once the screen width becomes smaller. I don't think this is the case, though, because allowing overflow to happen in the first place omits scrolling... At that point, the browser would simply begin to chop off content... which is true of any website responsive or not.

Comment: This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ajqx2b7g/1/) is 95% of the way there. Anyone know how to get the scrolling snap to be more scrolly and less snappy (such that the image seems to slide)?

Comment: Apparently super easy [scroll snapping can be done with CSS](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/css-scroll-snap-points). No JS required :)